# Methods for automating SQL CU patching?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, patching

For reasons that are not mine to address, we are looking for alternatives to [WSUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/get-started/windows-server-update-services-wsus) and [SCCM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/sum/understand/software-updates-introduction) to automate SQL CU patching (*particularly on SQL 2017+*)

There are some neat Powershell solutions like [this one by Adam Bertram](https://4sysops.com/archives/update-multiple-sql-server-systems-with-powershell/) which I found via the related post [Automate the patching of SQL Severs on Windows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/182287/21924)

I know there are a plethora of commercial solutions, that Google finds easily.  I am looking for solutions we can manage in house.

I am looking for other approaches to consider as well.  After extensive searching the only other approach I can even imagine is a SQL job, that runs on server restart (*server patching occurs regularly generally with restart*) that would go look in a shared folder for the most current CU and apply it if not installed. But I don't find any mention of solutions other the those above.

Are there any methods for automating SQL CU patching, that I have not found examples of?

If SQL job patching is viable, are there any examples?

Answer (score 5):

I would not go with SQL agent running Patch to upgrade sql server. During patching and/or after patching SQL server needs to be restarted along with a reboot of windows machine - depending on the files that are locked during patching.

Alternatives are described in my answer here : https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105837/8783

Also, [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/) has **[Update-DbaInstance.ps1](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/development/functions/Update-DbaInstance.ps1)** that can perform installation of SQL Server Service Packs and Cumulative Updates on local and remote servers.